# JTable Highlight a specific table on an update

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I cant find the answer to this anywhere - i am sure it is really simple but im quite confused!

i want to change the colour of the cell background when the value changes. 
I have written a cell renderer below:

```
public class CyanTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    cell.setBackground( Color.CYAN );
    return cell;
}
}
```

I want to pass the value of the cell from the event in the listener - to highlight the cell.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: I couldnt find anything that could help me there - i want to do something like: table.setCellBackground(int row, int col, Color col)

Comment: read again - particularly the paragraphs about renderer :-) That's the swingish way of doing a "tableCellBackground"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @mKorbel, `prepareRenderer()` can apply changes to *any* selected renderer. Alternatively, you can condition the color based on the `isSelected` parameter of your renderer.

```
if (isSelect) {
    this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
}
```

If you just want to change the default background color for *selected* cells, alter the `UIManager` property `Table.selectionBackground` early in your program. This will affect *all* tables during execution.

```
UIManager.put("Table.selectionBackground", Color.cyan);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) I don't undarstand what's `i have a tableModelListener that works.` to do with Renderer, maybe you have to mentioned that

2) you can use `preparedRenderer`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)

Comment: i have removed the ambuguity of the listener comment. I cant see how i can use the prepared renderer and pass the cell row and column values to highlight?