# How to add a data in JTable?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

I'm using netbeans and there is a table there. I just want to add data to it using a textfield and a button click.
I'm just exploring. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything? (By searching etc)?

Comment: Yeah.
All I can see is about database and so on.

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904316/how-to-add-data-to-jtable-created-in-design-mode

Comment: Is that applicable on netbeans?

Comment: I just want a simple code.

Comment: Yes, it is applicable on Netbeans.

Comment: Then what can I use?
For example:
Frame2 f = new Frame2();
f.txt.setText(txt1);
Is it like that on JTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add rows dynamically, you want to make use of the `DefaultTableModel`. By default on NetBeans, the `TableModel` given to `JTables` are `DefaultTableModel`. You can its methods and API [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).

What you want to do is use the methos `addRow(...)`, which will update your table for you every time you add a row.

You can use the graphical design view to set the headers.

1. Highlight/select the table from design view.
2. Go to the properties window on the right.
3. Click the <kbd>...</kbd> on the right of the **model** property
4. In the **Table Setting** tab set the rows to 0 and the number of columns you want. You can click on each column to give it a title header.

When you want to add rows dynamically, say after entering text in a few fields you can do something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
    String firstName = jTextField1.getText();
    String mi = jTextField2.getText();
    String lastName = jTextField3.getText();

    String[] row = {firstName, mi, lastName};
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Where can I put that DefaultTableModel?
Sorry, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Like I said, it's already the default in Netbeans for your table. You're just retrieving it using this `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTbable1.getModel();`

Comment: Do you know how to get the `actionPerformed` method into your code?

Comment: Yep, I already know about event.
I tried to copy: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTbable1.getModel(); But it doesn't work

Comment: Do you have a `jTbable1`? The spelling is messed up. Look at it. Make sure it matched your `Jtable` variable

Comment: I've changed the name to jTable2 because it's what I have.
I really don't know what to do. :(
sorry

Comment: Are you getting a compile error or a runtime exception?

Comment: Nope.
There's an error on: DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTbable1.getModel();
[Red underline on DefaultTableModel]

Comment: What does the error say when highlight it?

Comment: Did you change the name to `jTable2` instead of `jTbable1`?

Comment: `.. (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();`

Comment: "Cannot find symbol"
Yep, I've already changed it

Comment: You probably need to import it. Just hit `Ctrl + Shift + I` to resolve the import

Comment: What happens the that GUI Builder uses the fully qualified name with all its classes like `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` and don't use import statements. So when you try and just use `DefaultTableModel`, it can't find the symbol because the package hasn't been imported. I prefer to use imports. But if you wanted to make it work without the imports, you could also use `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` instead of just `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: Yes! It's working!!!!
Thank you so much!!
Just want to know, what happens when I hit Ctrl+Shift+I ?
There will be a code addition?

Comment: Yes if you know about import statements, all that does is add all the imports for you that you need. So when you do that, you will see `import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;` at the top of your code

Answer (score 1):

Example:

Create the columns:

```
String[] columnNames = {"School Name",
                    "Module Name",
                    "Grade",
                    "# of Years",
                    "Graduaded"}
```

Add data:

```
Object[][] data = {
{"Some High School", "Computing",
 "A", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
{"Some other High school", "Maths"
 "A", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
};
```

Constructor:

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

I'm not using any IDE. I hope that this gives you an insight though.
More info at:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple

Comment: Thanks for this. :D
I'll try to use this :)