# How to add image to JTable cell?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, imageicon

I have a JTable that was created in Netbeans's design mode. In my code, I opted for placing the following line of code on startup:

```
model = new TableModel();
tbShares.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
tbShares.setModel(model);
```

`tbShares` is my JTable object.

The JFrame that contains my JTable is shown below:

[image: share manager]

The first column was set as an `Object` type (the other two are Strings), so it can show an image. I have this code that I typed up for it to load an image, but it's not working (the `list.add` part, the rest is to give you an insight on how my code is structured). This is the extension of an `AbstractTableModel`.

```
public void addRegister(String status, String name, String clients){
        ImageIcon activeStatus = new ImageIcon(CleanSheets.class.getResource("res/img/active.png"));
        ImageIcon inactiveStatus = new ImageIcon(CleanSheets.class.getResource("res/img/inactive.png"));
        list.add(new Register((status.equals("true") ? activeStatus : inactiveStatus), name, clients));
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    class Register{
        Object status;
        String name;
        String clients;

        public Register(Object status, String name, String clients) {
            this.status = status;
            this.name = name;
            this.clients = clients;
        }
    }
```

Supposedly, it grabs the images from the folder I indicated, but then it's just outputting text in that column instead of the actual image. How do I get it to show the correct image? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should re-implement `TableCellRenderer` try to read [this](http://mdsaputra.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/swing-hack-show-image-in-jtable/) short article

Answer (score 1):

> ImageIcon activeStatus = new ImageIcon(CleanSheets.class.getResource("res/img/active.png"));
>           ImageIcon inactiveStatus = new ImageIcon(CleanSheets.class.getResource("res/img/inactive.png"));

- prepare `Icon/ImageIcon` as local variable, because `Renderer` recreating these `Objects` on each of `Mouse or Key events`, there are a bunch events in crazy period

> this.fireTableDataChanged();

- is correct notifier for add / remove whole `JTable` contens, for TableCell there are `fireTableCellXxx()`
- in this context is (add only one row to the `TableModel`) about `fireTableRowsInserted()`

> How do I get it to show the correct image?

- as I see there you add a new row with, then add `Icon / ImageIcon` to the `TableModel` directly, no more conversion, declare required, no issue, JTable has implemented `Icon / ImageIcon` in the API
- don't use Renderer if `Icon / ImageIcon` aren't changed form `Mouse or Key events`

Comment: Alright, I've put those as local variables. fireTableRowsInserted() asks for a row and column, though. How do I get the current row and column that was inserted? And as for ImageIcon, I'm lost on that part. The image changes when a share is enabled/disabled, because the share's icon has to be updated.

Comment: did you read API, not isn't it [this.fireTableRowsInserted(data.size() - 1, data.size() - 1);](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)

Comment: Yes, that implementation uses Vectors to store data, that has nothing to do with mine. I did it with this.fireTableRowsInserted(tbShares.getRowCount(), tbShares.getColumnCount()); However, that is not my main goal - I just want to get the image showing.

Comment: huuuuh your're respectful man ???? this is about AbstractTableModel, not about your concrete structure????, better would be to check [JTable tutorial about TableModel and Renderer too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Comment: Okay...? That is why I asked a specific question on Stack Overflow, so people with more expertise would not judge me and try to help me out instead of criticizing me. I have explained many times that I only wish to get the image working. But since you keep referring to documentation that I have already read, I will no require no further 'help' from you. Have a good day, sir.