# Adding an object to and retrieving an from a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel, defaulttablemodel

Let's assume that I have a class like this:

```
public Class FooBar {
  String foo;
  String bar;
  String unvisibleField;
  String id;
}
```

Then I have created a table using `DefaultTableModel` and adding elements to it like this (I am not showing all attributes of the class to the user):

```
for(int i=0;i<fooBarList.size();i++){
  model.addRow(new String[]{fooBarList.get(i).getFoo(), fooBarList.get(i).getBar()});
}
```

But I want to retrieve the FooBar class object from the table. Something like this:

`model.getRow()` will return a FooBar object
So probably I will also need something like

```
model.addRow(FooBar item)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure you'll only be returning FooBar object you just have to cast the objectsof the model into FooBar

Answer (score 1):

- this easiest and direct (and correct too) way how to add a new data to `(Abstract/Default) TableModel`
- please try and read [Row Table Model/List Table Model by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for your idea to put / synchronize `FooBar item`
- on this forum are answers how to implementing [AbstractTableModel based on HashXxx or List](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bjava%5D%20%5Bswing%5D%20%5Bjtable%5D%20abstracttablemodel), you have to check if [methods in the AbstractTableModel firing right and required events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)