# auto update jtable columns when model changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I've got a class which implements the TableModel Interface.
When I call setModel on my jTable and set my class as the model and then call `jTable.updateUI();`everything is fine.
But in some circumstances I want to change the model with a different structure. Displaying the data still works fine but my columns are not updated. Is there a way of forcing my table to also refresh the columns from new model?

Comment: Your model implementation is incorrect. Application code _never_ calls updateUI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model needs to fire the according event, e.g.: fireTableStructureChanged, if both the data and the structure changed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire

Comment: but I'm not extending `AbstractTableModel` I'm using the interface

Comment: follows link (added +1) this answer is correct to your too wide question, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Most likely, you really should. DefaultTableModel is a very data centric approach rather than an Object Oriented approach, which leads to many design issues. A custom model (usually based on AbstractTableModel) on the other hand can wrap around a list of objects.

Comment: You write you have a class which implements TableModel. Then you have to make sure to notify the listeners if there were some changes. AbstractTableModel provides some helper methods.

Answer (score 4):

- `jTable.updateUI();` is Look and Feel relevant method, don't use that

> I've got a class which implements the TableModel Interface.

- [you have to override right notifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968) for methods from `TableModel`
- use `DefaultTableModel`, there are all notifiers implemented in the API,
- all updates must be done on `EventDispatchThread`

Comment: But my model also extends from `Observer` so I cannot simply change to also extending `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: java.util.Observer is an interface or what Observer are you talking about?

Comment: AH excuse me I meant `Observable`

Answer (score -1):

If like me you are just writing a small hack, you may consider using the .repaint() method, instead of the .updateUI() method.

I used this because I don't use a TableModel, but I just have data in a Object[][], just like in the first example of the sun (well oracle) tutorial

Comment: no, repaint isn't needed with a well-behaved model (and note: there's _always_ a model driving the JTable - it might be an immutable implementation, though)

Answer (score -1):

Try this (insert after setModel(myTableModel); line):

```
myJTable.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
```

In my case it solved the update issue, while: .repaint(), .invalidate(), .fireTableDataChanged() didn't help.

Comment: no, that's not a method to call by application code: happens automatically on setModel (provided you did't change the default true value of autoCreateColumns). If it appears to help in your context, something is wrong elsewhere