# Weird behaviour on fireTableDataChanged in JTable

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Up till now I had a definition of the JTable like this:

```
    JTable table = new JTable(model) {
        @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            TradeTableModel model = (TradeTableModel) getModel();
            if ((Boolean) model.getValueAt(row, model.findColumn("Select"))) {
                Side s = (Side) model.getValueAt(row, model.findColumn("Side"));
                if (s == Side.BUY)
                    c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                else
                    c.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else {
                c.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
```

This was to make sure the rows will change color based on selecting the boolean column value. At my `AbstractTableModel` I specified set value method as follows:

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    assert columnIndex == 5;

    try{
        Selectable t = trades.get(rowIndex);
        t.setSelected((Boolean)aValue);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        //fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
    catch(Exception  e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object to set was not subtype of boolean");
    }
```

}

If I use `fireTableDataChanged()` the color is updated as I click the checkbox on the gui. Howver, I really want to send the `fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex)` as other handlers need to know the location of the cell. However, in this scenario, the row only changes if I click on other row in the table, as if it was delayed and waited for some other event to happen.

ANy ideas why that is the case?

Comment: the fireXX needs to include all model values that might be affected by setValueAt(..). Depending on the exact context, it should fire a slightly more broad event: f.i. if some condition somewhere else in the row is affect, fire a tableRowUpdate. Or if some other rows might be affected, fire a tableRowsUpdated(0, getRowCount())

Comment: IF you want to use fireTableCellUpdated, I would suggest you need to fire two events.  I the first is to notify that the OLD selected cell has changed and the second is to notify that the NEW selected cell has changed.  The important thing to remember here is that the JTable's paint process is highly optimised, so calling cellUpdated will generally only update that cell and won't effect any other cells

Comment: I decided to fire two events: one for the row, to change its paint, then cell updated event to do further processing on that particular cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (unseen) `TableModel` should `fireTableXxxXxxx()` as required in order to notify all listeners. `DefaultTableModel` does this automatically; `AbstractTableModel` should do so in `setValueAt()`. One such listener is the table itself. If "other handlers need to know the location of the cell," they can [register](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) for `TableModelEvent` instances via `addTableModelListener()`. They can also listen for [*User Selections*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) as needed.

Answer (score 2):

- have to notify proper method, `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);`
- more about [AbstractTableModel and prepareRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968)  and its methods, please read comment by `@camickr`
- have look at `convertXxxToModel` in the case that `JTable` is filtered or sorted, e.i.

Comment: So I need to simply repaint and revalidate the table to make the perpareRenderer to be invoked?

Comment: not this job is done by defaul by `prepareRenderer`, are you tried to `redirect / change` value for `prepareRenderer` from `Boolean value` to another `column`, and I'd to suggest wrapp Coloring or formating into `if (table.getRows > 0)` to protect against `XxxException`...