# How to resize JTable columns programmatically, DefaultTableModel Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable, defaulttablemodel

Because i don't understand the problem i don't know how to ask a good question. But i simply want to resize the columns in JTable. I use JTable and DefaultTableModel class to create the columns, but some columns take to much space, for example check buttons. I wonder if someone knows how to minimize these columns programmatically.

Here is some code i use

```
public static final String[] COLUMNS = {"Närvaro / Frånvaro", "Deltagare", "Ärendenummer", "Avvikelse"};
private CheckBoxDefaultTableModel model = new CheckBoxDefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 0);
private final JTable table = new JTable(model);

class CheckBoxDefaultTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

private List<String> removedItemsList = new ArrayList<String>();

public CheckBoxDefaultTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount) {
    super(columnNames, rowCount);
}
 Object[] row = {Boolean.FALSE, namn, caseNbr, null};
```

I don't have reputation to add a picture of my program, but it looks like in this link:

https://www.google.se/search?q=DefaultTableModel+java&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIx8-2na2uyAIVSY8sCh2KhQ4R&biw=1093&bih=522#tbm=isch&q=DefaultTableModel+java+gui&imgrc=tWPQqLj7FDfIBM%3A

Comment: A complete, working example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32919867/230513).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now :)

Comment: This was needed:  TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel(); and then,  tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(2);

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Thanks, i will do that

Answer (score 1):

This was needed to resize JTable columns,

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();       
tcm.getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(110);
tcm.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(2);
```

To center a JTable cell value,

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
```