# JTable from AbstractTableModel not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Im using Window Builder plugin in eclipse to make all the visual components, and i add a JTable, and at first it was a simple JTable, and it show the data correctly. Since i need that the data of the JTable be non-editable, i create a model to use the method isCellEditable. my code is this.

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames;
        private Object[][] data;

        public MyTableModel(Object[][] sentdata, String[] cnames){
            columnNames = cnames;
            data = sentdata;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable (int row, int column){
            return false;
        }

    }//fin del modelo
```

and in the constructor of the class is this

```
String[] NombresdeColumnas = {"Nombre del Producto", "Cantidad en Inventario", "Precio Unitario"}; 
RegistroInventario inventariodatos = new RegistroInventario();
Object[][] data = inventariodatos.regresarInventario();

MyTableModel model1 = new MyTableModel(data, NombresdeColumnas);

Table_Inventario = new JTable(model1);
Table_Inventario.setGridColor(Color.gray);

JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane_1.setViewportView(Table_Inventario);
```

and it doesnt show anything, but when i was doing this:

```
Table_Inventario = new JTable(data, NombresdeColumnas);
```

it was working just fine, i don´t know if the error has todo with de Window Builder form eclipse or in the code cause im new doning JTables.

Answer (score 2):

your issue is `return 0;` in

```
public int getColumnCount() {
```

and

```
public int getRowCount() {
```

use `DefaultTableModel` instead, sure if isn't there really important issue to use `AbstractTableModel` for `Object[][]` data or `Vector of Vectors`

usage of `AbstractTableModel` make me sence for model based on `HashMap` or `java.util.List` e.i.

Comment: thanks man i thought does methods were not taht important, i thing a will search a little more in detail about the AbstractTableModel.

Comment: [can start with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900628/refreshing-background-color-for-a-row-in-jtable/6901508#6901508)

Answer (score 2):

Your `AbstractTableModel` does not contain any data.

You indicate it contains zero rows and zero columns by your implementation of the `getColumnCount` and `getRowCount` methods.

And even when you adjust those methods, you do not use the data passed in the constructor as you always return `null` in the `getValueAt` method.

I think you should start reading the ['How to create a `TableModel`'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) section from the table tutorial