# Adding rows in to jtable by customized table model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I Have created a table model extending DefaultTableModel.

```
public class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
List<VariableDetails> data;
public AttachedVariableTableModel(){
super();        
this.data=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<VariableDetails>());
}

//method for adding rows
public void addRow(VariableDetails varDetails){

    this.data.add(varDetails);
    fireTableRowsInserted(this.data.size()-1,this.data.size()-1);
    }

}
```

I tried to add rows to the table which has already data in it.

```
tModel.addRow(new  VariableDetails());
```

but rows cannot be added. There is no exceptions and errors. what is actually wrong here? How Can i Solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the code shown here your full table model ? Since you are not using the `data` variable. Adding `data` to that variable has no effect

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. for why reason is there `super();`
2. `DefaultTableModel` can add `Object[]` or `Vector`
3. have to override `AbstractTableModel`, rather than `DefaultTableModel`, have to override all [`get/set` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968), with proper `fireXxxXxx()` in the methods, otherwise there aren't something visible in view (`JTable`)
4. can start with [List Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/) or [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/)

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest you a complete table model example to undestand how it works. It also uses a List as data. The most important thing is you need to extends **AbstractTableModel** to use your own variable in order to store data. Here is a complete sample of source code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

    public class MouseClickTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1807522184370383957L;

        private final String[] columnNames = { "Sr", "X", "Y", "Delay (ms)",
                "Comment" };

        public final Class[] mColTypes = { Integer.class, Integer.class,
                Integer.class, Integer.class, String.class };

        private final List<MouseClick> data;

        public MouseClickTableModel(){
            data = new ArrayList<MouseClick>(10);
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            final MouseClick currentRow = (MouseClick) data.get(row);

            switch (col) {
            case 0:
                return currentRow.getSequNb();
            case 1:
                return currentRow.getXcoo();
            case 2:
                return currentRow.getXycoo();
            case 3:
                return currentRow.getDelay();
            case 4:
                return currentRow.getComment();
            }

            return new String();
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return mColTypes[c];
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return false;
        }

        public void updateRow(Object value, int row, int col) {

        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's data can change.
         */
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            MouseClick currentRow = null;
            if (row >= data.size()) {
                // new data
                currentRow = new MouseClick();
                data.add(0, currentRow);
            }
            // update row
            else {
                currentRow = (MouseClick) data.get(row);
            }

            switch (col) {
            case 0:
                currentRow.setSequNb(((Integer) value).intValue());
                break;
            case 1:
                currentRow.setXcoo(((Integer) value).intValue());
                break;
            case 2:
                currentRow.setXycoo(((Integer) value).intValue());
                break;
            case 3:
                currentRow.setDelay(((Integer) value).intValue());
                break;
            case 4:
                currentRow.setComment(((String) value).toString());
                break;
            }
            // update
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        public MouseClick getData(int row) {
            return data.get(row);
        }

        public void addMouseClick(MouseClick mc) {
            insertMouseClick(getRowCount(), mc);
        }

        public void insertMouseClick(int row, MouseClick mc) {
            data.add(row, mc);
            fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }

        public void removeMouseClick(int row) {
            data.remove(row);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        }

    }
```

Then you just have to update your model with your ui design.

```
JTable table = new JTable(new MouseClickTableModel());
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
MouseClickTableModel model = getTable().getModel());
model.insertMouseClick(0, new MouseClick(0, Integer.valueOf(xValue),  Integer.valueOf(yValue), 2000, "comment"));
```