# How to force jTable to be not editable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

What I know that theoretically you can force a jTable to be non-editable by creating an AbstractTableModel and override the following method by always returning false all the time (eventhough this is not necessary due to the fact that the default method from the AbstractTableModel is already returning false).

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
   return false;
}
```

It seems though that I still can't figure out how to make this work right for my code. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Datagrid extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1080095595481949205L;
    private String[] title;
    private String[][] data;
    private JTable table;
    private JFrame frm;

    public Datagrid(String[] title, String[][] data) {
        this.title = title;
        this.data = data;

        create_table();
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    private void create_table() {
        table = new JTable(data, title);

        frm = new JFrame();
        frm.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return table.getColumnCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return table.getRowCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return table.getValueAt(row, column);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (it will need a `main(String[])` to put it on-screen.   2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556).  Particularly, `frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` will cause problems if `create_table()` is called multiple times. 3) `create_table()` Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: You haven't set table model to the JTable

Comment: @cubanacan You should make this an answer

Comment: Here is one more problem, if you do `table.setModel(this)` you should get `StackOverflowError`, because when you invoke `table.getRowCount()` it invokes `getModel().getRowCount()`

Comment: @cubanacan You need to make these into an answer, you'll get an up-vote from me

Comment: thanks to @AndrewThompson and @cubanacan! I've already changed it. You guys are great and damn fast! I would give you all a +1 if you tell me how i can do it :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have just posted an answer with all problems and solution for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here:

1. You haven't set table model to the JTable.
2. If you set your table model you will get `StackOverflowError`, because when you invoke `table.getRowCount()` it invokes `getModel().getRowCount()`.
3. If you set your table model you will not get column titles specified in constructor. Look at javadoc of method [AbstractTableModel#getColumnName(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#getColumnName%28int%29) for details.

Here is runnable and working solution based on your code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Datagrid extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1080095595481949205L;
    private String[] title;
    private String[][] data;
    private JTable table;
    private JFrame frm;

    public Datagrid(String[] title, String[][] data) {
        this.title = title;
        this.data = data;

        create_table();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] columnTitles = {"Title 1", "Title 2"};
        String[][] tableData = {{"Value 1", "Value 2"}, {"Another Value 1", "Another Value 2"}};
        new Datagrid(columnTitles, tableData);
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    private void create_table() {
        table = new JTable(data, title);
        table.setModel(this);
        frm = new JFrame();
        frm.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return data[row][column];
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return title[column];
    }

}
```

Comment: remove to create a GUI from Model

Comment: ok, what i am now gonna do is creating a TableModel with parameters (String[] title, String[][] data). 

Also I am gonna create a new class which extends JTable where i'm gonna add my additional methods and listeners.

Finally i will call those two in my main class by doing the following:
[View Code](https://snipt.net/bamboocha/-1155/) - 
Is that correct now? :)

Comment: @bamboocha yes, it is better, but you really don't need class which extends `JTable`, if you are not going to extend some UI capabilities, listeners shoud go into controller class. Consider using [MVC](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1524) pattern.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't create UI elements from within models...

Second of all, don't create UI elements from out side the Event Dispatching Thread

Third of all (as pointed out by cubanacan), you've not applied the model to the the table...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TableModel model = new Datagrid(); // <-- Create a new instance of the model
            table = new JTable(model);         // <-- Apply it to the table..

            frm = new JFrame();
            frm.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
            frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frm.pack();
            frm.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

cubanacan is on fire...

Fourthly, the following is going to crash your program.  These methods are called by the table in order for it figure put how to configure itself.

```
public int getColumnCount() {
    return table.getColumnCount();
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return table.getRowCount();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return table.getValueAt(row, column);
}
```

You should referencing the internal data structures you are trying to model.

You might find it help to read through [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: great, thank you! Seems like i just now started to realize how this stuff needs to be done..

Answer (score 2):

- not an answer to `isCellEditable`, to remove from `AbstractTableModel`

.

```
public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
}

private void create_table() {
    table = new JTable(data, title);

    frm = new JFrame();
    frm.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

- separate view and model logics
- in this form (missing `add`, `remove` row, `setValueAt(...)`) isn't possible to store any changes from `JTables` view to the `AbstractTableModel`
- miss there `ColumnClass`
- all data for `JTable`s view are stored in `XxxTableModel`
- [quite correct `AbstractTableModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968) for implemented methods in API (`Object[]`/`Double[]`/`String[]`... and `Vector<Object>`/`Vector<String>` ... )

Comment: First of all: thank you! Changing my table is not necessary due to the fact, that I only need to display my retrieved data from my database. Same is for ColumnClass. Why then should I implement them?