# SQLServerException: The result set is closed

Tags: java, sql-server

I am attempting to populate a jTable from a resultSet using SQLServer with the MS Driver 3.0.

The table will generate as long as I do not close the resultset, statement or connection.  If I close them, then my table replies back with the message:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is closed.
```

I attempted to create my tablemodel using the "How to use Tables" tutorial.

Here is my Table Model:

```
TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
                private String[] columnName = {"Employee ID", "Job Start", "Job ID",     "Oper. ID", "Indir. ID"};

            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columns;
            }

            public int getRowCount() {
                return rows;
            }

            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                try {
                    rs.absolute(row+1);
                    return rs.getObject(col+1);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
                return null;

            }
            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columnName[col];
            }
        };
```

My connections were originally done in a try with resources block, but in trying to find the issue I put it into a try-catch-finally block with the rs.close(), stmt.close(), and connection.close().  As I mentioned above, it will work fine if I do not have the close statements, but if I have them, then it states that the resultset is closed by the time it gets to the getValueAt method in my Table Model.

My whole code is here:

```
package dashboard;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import org.omg.CORBA.DATA_CONVERSION;


public class Dashboard extends JFrame {



      ResultSet rs;
        Connection connection;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSetMetaData md;
    JScrollPane scrollpane;
    int columns, rows;
    JFrame frame;
    String connectionUrl;

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public Dashboard() throws SQLException {


        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

            //Count number of rows
            rs.last();
            rows = rs.getRow();
            rs.first();

            //Get column Count
            columns = md.getColumnCount();



            TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel() {
                private String[] columnName = {"Employee ID", "Job Start", "Job ID", "Oper. ID", "Indir. ID"};

                public int getColumnCount() {
                    return columns;
                }

                public int getRowCount() {
                    return rows;
                }

                public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                    try {
                        rs.absolute(row+1);
                        return rs.getObject(col+1);
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        System.err.println(ex);
                    }
                    return null;

                }
                public String getColumnName(int col) {
                    return columnName[col];
                }
            };


            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

            scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
            getContentPane().add(scrollpane);

            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setTitle("Employee Dashboard");
            frame.setBounds(300, 300, 1300, 750);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.add(scrollpane);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {

        Dashboard me = new Dashboard();

    }
}
```

Update 6-4-13

I ended up tossing everything out and starting from scratch based on what @Reimeus said.  I am not positive, but I think this is working.  When I out print `model.getRowCount()` it tells me that it has the same rows as my query.  The code is here:

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[numberOfColumns];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i) {
                rowData[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);

            }
            model.addRow(rowData);
            System.out.println(model.getColumnName(1));

        }
```

The issue I am having now is that I cannot generate a table with the table model.  Here is what I thought would have worked:

```
 JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollpane);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.add(scrollpane);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

In my mind I am thinking:

DB to RS
RS to Table Model
TM to Table
Table to ScrollPane
ScrollPane to Jtable

I am sure it is something dumb that I am doing but I am still not knowledgeable enough to recognize it yet.

Comment: This is behaving as expected. What is the question?

Comment: Jeez, I was so nervous to post here that I actually forgot to ask any sort of question.  My question is, why is my resultset closing before my getValueAt method?  I have been looking at different examples over the last few days, and have been trying to use those as examples of how to do mine.  I had it working with vectors just fine, but then I found out vectors were deprecated, and now I gotten to where I know that my resultset contains the data, I just want to put it into the table.  In my mind this makes sense, but I am definitely a beginner and have come here as a last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ResultSet` is closed when `TableModel#getValueAt` is invoked as Swing uses an event model  to retieve the elements from `TableModel`. This occurs asynchronously, i.e. not on the main UI thread. Don't leave database resources such as `Statement` and `ResultSet` open. These create an overhead on the database itself.

Update the `TableModel` based on JDBC queries then close the associated database resources. Don't use `ResultSet` methods for populating the model.

Have a look at [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). It shows how fixed backing data is used to hold the data for the `TableModel`. Alternatively an `ArrayList` may be used.

If you're starting out, `DefaultTableModel` is easy to use and is mutable. Later you can progress to managing the update of the model such as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900628/refreshing-background-color-for-a-row-in-jtable?answertab=oldest#tab-top) from @mKorbel

Aside: Use `PreparedStatement` rather than `Statement` to protect against SQL Injection attacks

Comment: I will research PreparedStatements and make sure I use them in lieu of Statements.

Concerning my error, your explanation makes perfect sense why it is closed. I understand that now.  Thank you.

You mention "Update the TableModel based on JDBC queries". Do you by chance have any suggestions on where I can learn more about how to update the Table Model using JDBC like you are suggesting? I would like to do this right and effectively, and it is obvious that the resources I am currently using are not leading me down the correct path.

Comment: I will take a look at what you have suggested tomorrow and I will see if I can get it working.

Comment: I think I cannot see the forest for the trees. I may be making this much more complicated than it needs to be. As I understand it currently: database->ResultSet->TableModel->Table.  Is that the right way to do it, or am I missing/adding a step?  If this is the correct way, then it seems my trouble is in getting the result set into the table model correctly.  My end goal is a table that refreshes every x amount of time to reflect whether people have clocked in or out.  Am I even approaching this the right way?

Comment: Yes, just update the `TableModel` when required but don't use the `ResultSet` from within model itself. `DefaultTableModel` is easy when starting out.