# Java. JTable setValueAt data not update

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I try to use JTable but when I invoke setValueAt method data don't update in gui. I try to find the answer more then 5 hours but anything help me.

I try to updateUI and fireTableDataChanged() but id doesn't help.

I use AbstractTableModel and my constructor is JTable(MemoryTableModel).
Look at my code of MemoryTableModel:

What i`m doing wrong, or what I forget?

(Sorry for my english, its not my native language)

```
public class MemoryTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> memoryCells;
String[] columnNames = {"Offset", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
        "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

public MemoryTableModel(byte[] data, int cells) {
    super();
    memoryCells = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    for (int i=0; i< cells/16; i++) {
        ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
        a.add(i);
        for (int j=0; j<16; j++) {
            a.add(data[i*16+j]);
        }
        memoryCells.add(a);
    }
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return memoryCells.size();
}

public String getColumnName(int col){
    return columnNames[col];
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int line, int column) {
    return memoryCells.get(line).get(column);
}
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object cell, int row, int column) {
    memoryCells.get(row).set(column, cell);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0)
        return false;
    return true ; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- your notifier `fireTableDataChanged();` for `setValueAt(Object cell, int row, int column) {` is wrong
- you would need to use  [fireTableCellUpdated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29), more in linked  API
- for easier workaround to use `DefaultTableModel`, `Vector` or `util.List` as underlaing array for `AbstractTableModel`

EDIT

- quite common issue with `public boolean stopCellEditing() {` and I hope that there is somthing like as `JTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: I`m tried fireTableCellUpdated also early but it doesn`t help.

Comment: Also now i find one feature. If i invoke setValueAt method in one procedure it`s work fine, but if i invoke setValueAt method in another method it`s doesnt work

Comment: then edit your post with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, [you can to start with](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968), remove my renderers balast, put there your table model ....